# How to get a index of element in the array with Dlang?

Tags: d

I would like to get a index of array satisfying the condition.
Then, I'd like to get max of them.

With Ruby:

```
# normal array
array.index{|n| n>W }

# 2-dimensional array
matrix.map{|arr| arr.index{|n| n>W}}
```

How to do this with Dlang ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [countUntil](https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/searching/count_until.html), it accepts a predicate :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].countUntil!(c => c > 5).writeln;
```

To get the index of the max element, use the aptly name [maxIndex](https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/searching/max_index.html) function :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].maxIndex.writeln;
```